# Python - convert large json to csv

Tags: python, json

im a little new to python.
I want to convert json file to csv. the problem is that its big json file and its not a really json.
looks like this:

```
{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value3", "key3":"value3"}
{ "key1":"value4", "key2":"value5", "key5":"value6"}
```

not every json object have the same keys.

expected output:

```
key1   key2   key3   key5
value1 value3 value3   ""
value4 value5 ""    value6
```

and some of the values are url encoded `Hell%C3%B6%20W%C3%B6rld%40Python`

every time I try to do something its either freeze my pc or i cant iter on values to parse them.
I try to use pandas for this but i cant figure how to change the values in the json so it will be on the csv.

thank you.

Comment: Also post the expected output. in your case probably the expected structure of the csv

Comment: Well for the encoded strings you can use [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote), but for the rest it depends on your memory, so consider using and saving chunks instead of whole data.

Comment: This looks more like a dictionary than json...